# pip install pyublas fails with `NameError: name 'sys_platform' is not defined`

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

Under Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7.12 `sudo -H pip install pyublas` fails with the following stacktrace:

```
Collecting pyublas
  Using cached PyUblas-2013.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.35.tar.gz
    Extracting in /tmp/tmpnYhYMx
    Now working in /tmp/tmpnYhYMx/distribute-0.6.35
    Building a Distribute egg in /tmp/pip-build-vvsChR/pyublas
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 248, in <module>
        scripts = scripts,
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/tmp/tmpnYhYMx/distribute-0.6.35/setuptools/dist.py", line 225, in __init__
        _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/tmp/tmpnYhYMx/distribute-0.6.35/setuptools/dist.py", line 257, in finalize_options
        ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)
      File "/tmp/tmpnYhYMx/distribute-0.6.35/pkg_resources.py", line 2027, in require
        working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer))
      File "/tmp/tmpnYhYMx/distribute-0.6.35/pkg_resources.py", line 2237, in requires
        dm = self._dep_map
      File "/tmp/tmpnYhYMx/distribute-0.6.35/pkg_resources.py", line 2466, in _dep_map
        self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
      File "/tmp/tmpnYhYMx/distribute-0.6.35/pkg_resources.py", line 2499, in _compute_dependencies
        common = frozenset(reqs_for_extra(None))
      File "/tmp/tmpnYhYMx/distribute-0.6.35/pkg_resources.py", line 2496, in reqs_for_extra
        if req.marker_fn(override={'extra':extra}):
      File "/tmp/tmpnYhYMx/distribute-0.6.35/_markerlib/markers.py", line 109, in marker_fn
        return eval(compiled_marker, environment)
      File "<environment marker>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'sys_platform' is not defined
    /tmp/pip-build-vvsChR/pyublas/distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-vvsChR/pyublas/setup.py", line 143, in <module>
        main()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-vvsChR/pyublas/setup.py", line 29, in main
        from aksetup_helper import hack_distutils, get_config, setup, \
      File "aksetup_helper.py", line 3, in <module>
        distribute_setup.use_setuptools()
      File "distribute_setup.py", line 152, in use_setuptools
        return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
      File "distribute_setup.py", line 132, in _do_download
        _build_egg(egg, tarball, to_dir)
      File "distribute_setup.py", line 123, in _build_egg
        raise IOError('Could not build the egg.')
    IOError: Could not build the egg.
```

Following various related SO answers, I have confirmed that distribute is not installed, setuptools is up to date (`setuptools (36.0.1)`).

I have also tried manually running setup per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276498/python-pip-install-pyublas-could-not-build-the-egg/31632587#31632587) to no avail.

Comment: See https://documen.tician.de/pyublas/installing.html